# Word count debugging

Tags: c

On **K&R**, the following code is proposed to count words, lines and characters in input. Exercise 1.11 asks:

> How would you test the word count program? What kinds of input are
>   most likely to uncover bugs if there are any?

The only answer I see to these questions is testing the code on some input that contains several lines, words and tabs.

Can you see any other way to test this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1 /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */

/* count lines, words and characters in input */

main(){
    int c, n1, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    n1 = nw = nc = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++n1;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            ++ nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n",n1,nw,nc);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the program using all of the following types of inputs:

1. An empty file.
2. A file with only new lines and no words.
3. A file with very long words, all on one line.
4. A file with very long words, on many lines.
5. The program might produce invalid output, but should not crash if given special characters.
6. Test the program with "N" blank lines inserted at random locations throughout the document.
7. Test the program with "N" blank lines inserted at the beginning of the document.
8. Test the program with "N" blank lines inserted at the end of the document.

Test the program with both one character words and long words, including hyphenated words with these inputs:

1. A file with only one space separating each word.
2. A file with one space or "N" spaces separating each word.
3. A file with only one tab separating each word.
4. A file with one space or "N" tabs separating each word.
5. A file with only one space OR tab separating each word.
6. A file with one space or "N" spaces OR tabs separating each word.
7. Test the program with single quotes and double quotes, with and without spaces between the words and the quotes, and with nested levels of quotes.

Also:

1. Make sure the program doesn't count un-intended characters as a word or part of a word.  For example,  make sure a carriage return, which is a legal MS-DOS character is not counted as a word if it is included at the end of a line.
2. Create the largest possible file for which space was designated for this application, and make sure that the program does not crash, that other applications are NOT impacted, and that the output is correct.
3. Create the largest possible file for which space was designated for this application, containing only spaces, newlines and tabs, except for words at the end of the file, and make sure that the program does not crash, that other applications are NOT impacted, and that the output is correct.
4. Create the largest possible file for which space was designated for this application, containing only spaces, newlines and tabs, except for words at the beginning of the file, and make sure that the program does not crash, that other applications are NOT impacted, and that the output is correct.
5. Create the largest possible file for which space was designated for this application, containing only one very long word: the output of the program should be 1.
6. Have the program write a debugging file that contains a `printf` for each while, if, and else statement.  Make sure that the tests cause all of the printf statements to be reached.  In other words, there shouldn't be any parts of the code that remain unused at the end of the testing.
7. There should be a good reason the output doesn't match the output of the `wc` program.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind the question is to illustrate the concept of "white box" testing. Look at every "choice point in your program, and see how you can exercise the logic behind it to uncover the "corner cases":

- To exercise the `while` loop, feed it input that has no data (i.e. `EOF` comes right away)
- Feed the program a file with a single line and no `\n` before `EOF` to exercise the line counting `if`
- Feed the program a file with one or more lines composed entirely of whitespace characters
- Feed the program a file with the last `\n` missing, and see if the last word gets counted
- Feed the program a file with single-character words to exercise the logic of switching between `IN` and `OUT`